# SVG: positioning RECT based on value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

I'm wanting to recreate this graph

[image]

```
<div class="discrete" data-value="1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1"></div>
```

For each `1` I want to make a top half line, and `0` the opposite.

```
function discreteChart(self, dataset) {

  var w = parseInt(d3.select(self).style("width")),
        h = parseInt(d3.select(self).style("height")),

      svg = d3.select(self)
                         .append("svg")
                         .attr("width", w)
                         .attr("height", h),

      yScale = d3.scale
                        .linear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
                            .range([0, h]);

  svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr('fill', '#363636')
        .attr('rx', '1')
        .attr('ry', '1')
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return i * 3;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return h - yScale(d) / 1;
    })
    .attr("width", 1) // width of bar
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return yScale(d);
    });

}
```

My problem is I'm not entirely sure how to do this. I have the rectangles made but I can't place them into position.

http://jsfiddle.net/everina/1eec20xe/

Comment: For rendering lines, you might want to use [the `<line>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make line instead of rectangle as pointed by Anko.
Here is how you can make a line:

```
  svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr('stroke', '#363636')
    .attr('x1', function(d, i) {
      return (i + 1) * 10;//xposition of line
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d, i) {
      return (i + 1) * 10;
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d, i) {
      return 10;//starting point of line
    })
    .attr('y2', function(d, i) {
      if (d) {
        return 0; //if 0 then line should be below
      } else {
        return 20;//if non 0 then line should be above
      }
    })
```

working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/33dan9xw/2/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the chart scaleable, so the positions are correct for any height:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("rect")
    .attr('fill', '#363636')
    .attr('rx', '1')
    .attr('ry', '1')
.attr("x", function(d, i) {
  return i * 3;
})
.attr("y", function(d) {
  return d ? h / 2 : 0;
})
.attr("width", 1) // width of bar
.attr("height", function(d) {
    return h/2;
});
```